# per connection timeouts in netty

Tags: java, netty

I am using netty to write a client application and I'd like to set a connection timeout per connection. Right now I am doing something like:

```
Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
bootstrap.group(new EpollEventLoopGroup(1)).channel(EpollSocketChannel.class);
bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectionTimeoutSecs * 1000);
bootstrap.handler(new EmptyChannelInitializer());
```

This seems to work globally, but is there a way to specify something per connection? I didn't see any chance to do that in the `bootstrap.connect()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just set it in the `initChannel(...)` method via `channel.config().setOption(...)` or just create a new bootstrap (which can share the same `EventLoopGroup`.

Comment: Are bootstraps heavy weight objects? would it be a problem creating those per request in a client doing hundreds of requests per second? or is it just the EventLoopGroup that is important to share?

Comment: these are not heavy-weight at all. Just share the EventLoopGroup (the group is heavy weight).

Comment: thanks and i really enjoyed your book. very informative!